# Where do I store images permanently so that heroku app can access them, even though after the dynos cycling I need the images to be shown

Tags: django, python-3.x, visual-studio, heroku

I cannot buy AWS s3 or any other sort of storage spaces because I'm a student, so could you please give me any other solution for storing images permanently so that my heroku app can access them till my app stays alive.